# Send data from GSM module to cloud server like Firebase

Tags: arduino, gsm

I am trying to search for anything to send my sensor data from Arduino + GSM SIM900A to a cloud server, preferably Firebase. Does anyone know how can I achieve this operation to Firebase or any other cloud database?

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are a lot of possible solutions you can adopt...

Comment: I have tried with Thingspeak @rebatoma, but the problem with it is that there is a limit on the number of fields, and if somehow I manage to go about that, I am not able to send one big query to update all the fields at a time. My other system is running firebase, so I was thinking if I can use somewhat same type of db.

Comment: I have searched on the internet @jsotola, most people have used Thingspeak or Sparkfun database (expired as of right now). I have found something with firebase + PHP scripting but the problem is that the values are being updated in a 16-bit random field, which is I don't want. And if somehow I may not have a problem with that, then I am not able to understand how is their system working.

Comment: please read this ... https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem ... your last comment seems to describe the actual problem